# Realtime Database streaming Using Apache Spark and kfaka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

i am designing a spark streaming application with Kafka. i have few questions as follows :
i am streaming data from RDBMS tables into kafka and using Spark consumer to consume messages and process using Spark - SQL

Questions :
1. i am streaming data from table and streaming to kafka as (key as tablename, value as table data in form of JSON records) -- is this correct architecture ?

2. in spark consumer i am trying to consume data using DStream.foreachRDD(x => transformation to x RDD) -- i am having issue with this (it says error with transformation within transformation not allowed ... i am trying to extract keys within foreachRDD function to get table names and transform x.values using map function to convert back from JSON to normal string and then save each record to Spark-sql )

Is this architecture and design for database streaming OK and how can i solve transformation within transformation issue  ?

Regards,
Piyush Kansal

Comment: sharing your code where you are having error would be helpful to understand the error better.if possible please share code snippet

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use-case.

I use Nifi to Get the data from RDBMS Views and put into Kafka Topic.
I have a Topic for each View in Oracle Database with multiple partitions.
Using Nifi,  data will be converted into JSON format and put into Kafka.

Is there any requirement to use same kafka topic for all table data?

Below Code will be used to persist data into Cassandra.

```
> val msg = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder,
> StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
>   
>     /* Process Records for each RDD */   Holder.log.info("Spark foreach Starts")
>        val data = msg.map(_._2) 
>        data.foreachRDD(rdd =>{
>        if(rdd.toLocalIterator.nonEmpty)    {
>     
>     
>       val messageDfRdd = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
var data2=messageDfRdd .map(p => employee(p.getLong(1),p.getString(4),p.getString(0),p.getString(2),p.getString(3),p.getString(5)));

>  //code to save to Cassandra.   
>            }
```

Comment: i am just building a POC. so i am not sure if the design i am following is correct or not.
i just want to manupulate some data in eachRDD of Dstream based on some keys .

Comment: `code`
   val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val records:ReceiverInputDStream[(String, String)] = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc,kafkaParams,Map("MozartComposerDB" -> 5),StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
    val recordsKey = records.transform(x => x.groupByKey().keys)
    val arr =  sc.accumulator("")    // new ArrayBuffer[String]();
    recordsKey.foreachRDD{key => // Filter data in records Dstream based on each recordsKey)
    }



    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

 }

}

Comment: you can use reduceByKey or GroupByKey directly. don't need a transform.
   val data = msg.groupByKey()
   val key = data.map(_._1)
   val values = data.map(_._2)